# DIsplay data from one form to another in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have to make two forms on same vf page. My requirement is to populate the data entered in the first form to data fields in the second form(Both forms have same fields). How can I do it?
Help me with a sample code.

Comment: "Both forms have same fields": I would like to take a step back and ask: why do you need this? One place where I have seen this: when the elements of an invoice address must be copied to a delivery address. Then you could solve this by having a button to copy the elements, or a check box that states that the delivery address is the same as the invoice address.

Comment: It is as per the requiremnt. And It is a kind of two way confirmation on the same page itself (Actually very funny it is), but it is the requirement. Can you help me with a sample code

Comment: Did you try with inputfields with actionSupport and rerendering the second form? Please show us what you have done to achieve this, so we can give our suggestions.